# How to get list of object inside collection from cloud firestore in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[Here's the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUwVT.png)

How can I get the "listTask"

I've tried to log the "document.data["listTask"]" with the code below:

```
db.collection("project").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            Log.d(TAG, "onRefresh: loadProject")
            for (document in result){
                if (document.data["owner_id"]== id){
                    counter++
                    Log.d(TAG, "inside response: ${document.data["listTask"]}")
                }
            }

        }
```

and this is the log result

```
D/YourProjectFragment: inside response: [{id=29356, title=Database, status=false}, {id=28581, title=UI UX, status=false}, {id=66044, title=Architecture Design, status=false}, {id=77830, title=Functional Test, status=false}]
```

I don't know the pattern of the response, I have tried with `JSONArray` but that is not `JSONArray`.

so how to get the list of objects inside collection in Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried with `jsonArray` but that is not `jsonArray`

That's obviously not a `JSONArray`, it's a property of type object. Besides that, `JSONArray` is not a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

> So how to get the list of objects inside a collection in Cloud Firestore?

Unfortunately, you cannot map your `listTask` property directly into a list of custom objects. You should write some code for that. The `listTask` property is actually a list of Map objects, as your response states for:

```
response: [{id=29356, title=Database, status=false}, {id=28581, title=UI UX, status=false}, {id=66044, title=Architecture Design, status=false}, {id=77830, title=Functional Test, status=false}]
```

See, it begins with `[` and ends with `]`, this makes it an array and each and every object inside this array is a `Map`. So you need to iterate through this list of Map objects and create your own list of `Task` objects.

If you want, you can contact the Firebase team and make a request for that.

Comment: so how to iterate that?, what should i do with `document.data["listTask"]` how can i process that, i try `document.data["listTask"] as? Array<HashMap<Any, Any>>` but i think that is not the right way

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>`. So as long as inside that list you have `HashMap` object, get each and one of them out using an iteration.